# JSF: Button/Link without form submit

Tags: jsf, seam, java-ee-6, jboss-weld

In earlier projects I often used an s:button or s:link from Seam 2 when caceling something, because it wouldn't submit the form and thus no model updates occured.

Now I switched to WELD + Seam 3 and couldn't find it there anymore - am I just blind or do I have to use something else?

Geziefer

Comment: In the meantime I learned that it has really disappeared from Seam. So how would one implement a page action which should NOT submit the form in JSF 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to handle it by using the commandButton from RichFaces 4 and setting bypassUpdates to true:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{myHandler.cancel}"
bypassUpdates="true" render="myTable" />
```

For me this solution is ok, since I'm allready using RichFaces 4 - but I'm still interested, how to solve this with standard JSF 2.0?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in plain JSF 2.0 by setting `immediate` attribute to `true` in the `h:commandButton`.

From the MyFaces wiki:

> The immediate attribute can be used to achieve the following effects:
>
> Allow a commandLink or commandButton to navigate the user to
> another page without processing any data currently in input fields of
> the current screen. In particular, this allows navigation to occur
> even when there are currently validation errors. A "cancel" button
> typically falls into this category.
>
> Allow a commandLink or commandButton to trigger back-end logic
> while ignoring validation for some of the fields on the screen. This
> is a more general version of the item above.
>
> Make one or more input components "high priority" for validation,
> so that if any of these are invalid then validation is not performed
> for any "low-priority" input components in the same page. This can
> reduce the number of error messages shown.